# defer many tasks simultaneously on google-app-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, queue, deferred

I am developping a python app on google app engine. I have a CRON job which imports everyday a list of 20 fresh files from a S3 bucket to a GS bucket.

Here is my code:

```
import webapp2
import yaml
from google.appengine.ext import deferred

class CronTask(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        with open('/my/config/file') as file:
            config_dict = yaml.load(file_config_file)
        for file_to_load in config_dict:
            deferred.defer(my_import_function, file_to_load)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', CronTask)
], debug=True)
```

Note that `my_import_function` is part of another package and takes some time to be done.

My question: is it a good idea to use the function `deferred.defer` for this task or should I proceed diferently to launch `my_import_function` for all my arguments?

Comment: `deferred.defer` will work just fine and is a good way to get automatic retry for each `my_import_function` in case of intermittent failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the taskqueue, but depending on how many tasks you have you may not want to use `deferred.defer()`.

With `deferred.defer()` you can only enqueue one task per call.  If you are enqueueing a lot of tasks, that is really inefficient.  This is really slow:

```
for x in some_list:
    deferred.defer(my_task, x)
```

With a lot of tasks, it is much more efficient to do something like this:

```
task_list = []
for x in some_list:
    task_list.append(taskqueue.Task(url="/task-url",params=dict(x=x)))
taskqueue.Queue().add(task_list)
```

About a year ago, I did a timing comparison, and the latter was at least an order of magnitude faster than the former.

Comment: Are these tasks parallelized by default? What should I do to parallelize them?

Comment: @sweeeeeet, yes, the answer to your other recent question is applicable here as well.

Comment: Lets suppose that the tasks I sent to my Queue takes 2 hours each to be done. Since a task in a push queue has 10 minutes to complete, It may not be a good solution. What would be a good practice for such very long treatments, in order to treat them in a parallel way, but with unlimited time limit so they have time to finish?

Comment: @Kekito I'm sorry I don't see anywhere that you can only enqueue one task per call... As long as I know this is the same as using taskqueue. In fact deferred used it internally. The biggest limitation for me when using deferred is that you are limited to 100kb for the arguments size. If you exceed this size the deferred library will put a datastore entity automatically to hold the arguments... Therefore you may incur on some extra cost charges and overhead.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred

Comment: @sweeeeeet If you have such a heavy processing time for each task you need to cut the work done in smaller pieces and kickoff more tasks that process a little bit of information each and finish kicking another task until the hole work is done.

Comment: @janscas, I think we are not understanding each other.  I believe `deferred.defer()` can only take a single task at a time.  You can certainly call it more than once, but there is a lot of overhead each time you call it.  By contrast, with `taskqueue.Queue().add()` you can give it a list of tasks and eliminate most of the overhead.  It is the same as doing multiple puts versus a put_multi.